# Loop through array and delete indexes with same value

Tags: objective-c

I have an array, points, which contain some CGPoints values, which later on is added to an other array, data.

```
    CGFloat xpoint = [[points objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint = [[points objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint1 = [[points objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint1 = [[points objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint2 = [[points objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint2 = [[points objectAtIndex:5] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint3 = [[points objectAtIndex:6] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint3 = [[points objectAtIndex:7] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint4 = [[points objectAtIndex:8] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint4 = [[points objectAtIndex:9] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint5 = [[points objectAtIndex:10] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint5 = [[points objectAtIndex:11] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint6 = [[points objectAtIndex:12] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint6 = [[points objectAtIndex:13] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint7 = [[points objectAtIndex:14] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint7 = [[points objectAtIndex:15] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint8 = [[points objectAtIndex:16] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint8 = [[points objectAtIndex:17] floatValue];
    CGFloat xpoint9 = [[points objectAtIndex:18] floatValue];
    CGFloat ypoint9 = [[points objectAtIndex:19] floatValue];

[data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint,ypoint)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint1,ypoint1)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint2,ypoint2)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint3,ypoint3)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint4,ypoint4)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint5,ypoint5)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint6,ypoint6)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint7,ypoint7)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint8,ypoint8)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xpoint9,ypoint9)]];
```

I want to make a loop that loops through the array and checks for x-koordinates with the same value, and then delete the "oldest" value. 
Fx.

```
(x,y)
1,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

I want only one value with 2, but at the same time I want all the y-values, with x-values = 2, to added. And then deleting the values so only one x-value=2 is back. So I want the output tod be:

```
(x,y)
1,1
2,9
3,4
```

Please help me :)

Kind regards

Comment: I think you should accept at least some of the answers you have been given for your past questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop all the values and add them to a new array, whale also adding them to a dictionary that its key is the one you want to delete, so before adding, check if its already in the dictionary to know if its already added

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me with a snap of code for it?